# Finding url to send post request to

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm trying to grab data from this site: https://www.azjobconnection.gov/ada/mn_warn_dsp.cfm?def=false

I wrote the code below to enter the desired start date then post into the form. I expected to be taken to the page that pops up after you enter in the desired start date; the desired page has all the business you could click on to get additional data. I'm not getting that page. I think site security is blocking me or I'm doing something wrong. At the end of the day, I need to extract data from all of the WARN notices at the site.

I suspect maybe I'm not sending the POST request to the correct url; how do I find out the correct url to send the POST request to.

I got date4 as the date field from the inspect element; I suppose that could be wrong also.

```
import requests
params = {'date4': '01/01/2020'}
with requests.session() as s:
 r = s.post("https://www.azjobconnection.gov/ada/mn_warn_dsp.cfm?securitysys=off&amp;FormID=0", data=params)
site_text = r.text
```

Comment: use `DevTools` in Firefox/Chrome (tab `Network`) to see all urls send from browser. But first check if page can work without JavaScirp because `requests` can't run JavaScript. And you should check requests with all headers used in web browser. Often if you don't have header "User-Agent" then server send different data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upon looking at this page, you are missing some request headers, specifically the authenticity token. To grab this, we must parse the HTML of the previous page to find it. Take a look at this quick example:

```
# Imports
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from requests import Session

# Session Object
session = Session()

# Add a user agent, so the request looks more human like.
session.headers.update({
    "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.97 Safari/537.36"
})

# Initial sesssion, you need to fetch the url first, so the authenticity
# token can be parsed out of the html
init_session = session.get(url="https://www.azjobconnection.gov/ada/mn_warn_dsp.cfm?def=false")

# Beautiful soup object, used for HTML parsing
soup = BeautifulSoup(init_session.content, "html.parser")

# Get all of the input tags
inputs = soup.findAll('input')


# Upon running, we see that the authenticity token, is the first element in the array.
authenticty_token = inputs[0]['value']

# Now we can make our request!

# Request data
data = {
    "authenticity_token" : authenticty_token,
    "coname": "", 
    "coName_ADAdefault": "", 
    "coName_verify_char[0|50]": "The value you have supplied for Company Name is too long.",
    "city": "", 
    "city_ADAdefault": "", 
    "city_verify_char[0|45]": "The value you have supplied for City is too long.",
    "zip": "", 
    "zip_ADAdefault": "", 
    "zip_verify_char[0|10]": "The value you have supplied for Zip/Postal Code is too long.",
    "sda": "", 
    "startdate": "01/01/2020",
    "startDate_ADAdefault": "mm/dd/yyyy",
    "startDate_verify_date4": "",
    "startDate_verify_char[0|45]": "The value you have supplied for Start Date is too long.",
    "enddate": "mm/dd/yyyy",
    "endDate_ADAdefault": "mm/dd/yyyy",
    "endDate_verify_date4": "", 
    "endDate_verify_char[0|45]": "The value you have supplied for End Date is too long.",
    "layoffType": "y",
    "search": "Search",
    "old_choice": 1,
    "ZIP_prev": "",
    "def_prev": "false",
    "CITY_prev": "",
    "SDA_prev": "",
    "STARTDATE_prev": "", 
    "CONAME_prev": "",
    "ENDDATE_prev": "",
    "FormName": "Form0",
}

# Get the data
get_warn_data = session.post("https://www.azjobconnection.gov/ada/mn_warn_dsp.cfm?securitysys=on&FormID=0", data=data)

# print the data, this looks messy, so lets prettify with bs4!
#print(get_warn_data.content) 


soup = BeautifulSoup(get_warn_data.content, "html.parser")

print(soup.prettify())
```

This will get you the HTML you are looking for. Now within this HTML, you will need to parse the a href tags to grab the links you need. For example, they will look like this:

```
<tr class="cfOutputTableRow cfAlternate">
             <td align="left" class="cfPadLeft cfAlternate" colspan="1" valign="top">
              <span class="blTransparent">
               <a href="mn_warn_dsp.cfm?id=399&amp;callingfile=mn_warn_dsp.cfm&amp;hash=0C2428869560C6832A1D929070C0278F">
                Aecom
               </a>
              </span>
             </td>
             <td align="left" class="cfAlternate" colspan="1" valign="top">
              <span class="blTransparent">
               Glendale
              </span>
             </td>
             <td align="left" class="cfAlternate" colspan="1" valign="top">
              <span class="blTransparent">
               85310
              </span>
             </td>
             <td align="left" class="cfAlternate" colspan="1" valign="top">
              <span class="blTransparent">
               7
              </span>
             </td>
             <td align="left" class="cfAlternate cfPadRight" colspan="1" valign="top">
              <span class="blTransparent">
               01/17/2020
              </span>
             </td>
            </tr>
```

Specifically:

```
<a href="mn_warn_dsp.cfm?id=399&amp;callingfile=mn_warn_dsp.cfm&amp;hash=0C2428869560C6832A1D929070C0278F">
```

Once you have grabbed this link, be sure to prepend https://www.azjobconnection.gov/ada/ to it.

```
https://www.azjobconnection.gov/ada/mn_warn_dsp.cfm?id=399&amp;callingfile=mn_warn_dsp.cfm&amp;hash=0C2428869560C6832A1D929070C0278F
```

Comment: Thanks Tyler. Does it matter what I input as the header? Does it matter that I'm using a windows system and not Mac? You asked what I'm trying to do: I'm trying to loop through all the companies that come up after you enter the date; I need to grab the number of people each company laid off.

Comment: It is always best to use a user agent in the header. It makes your request look more legitimate. It does not matter what type operating system you are using. You can use any user agent you'd like. Google windows user agents, or even obtain the user agent you are using by inspecting the request headers in your browsers developer tools. Though it is best practice to include all request headers, you really only need the authentication token, and the fields that you are looking for. The values that are left out of the data dict will be set to zero on the server side.

Comment: After running your code, I'm not seeing what I see when I enter a date at the actual page. After entering a start date, a list of companies should appear--"Aecom" should be the first company. You then click on each company to get the desired data. I cannot get to the list of companies.

Comment: You need to include all of the request headers. I updated my example. After you have that, you will need to parse the a href tags that contain the links for that specific company, the use a request to get the content of those links.

Comment: You're awesome Tyler.

Comment: Hey Tyler, I posted another question stemming from this problem. If you have time, please check it out. Thanks.                                                                                                 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62416246/grabbing-data-from-subsequent-pages-of-a-website